# Using GUID with SQL Server and NHibernate

Tags: asp.net, sql, nhibernate, sql-server-ce, guid

I'm running NHibernate and SQL Server CE I am trying to use GUIDs as my ID column.  This is the code I already have:

Mapping:

```
  <class name="DatabaseType" table="DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE">
    <id name="Id" column="DATABASE_TYPE_ID">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="DispName" />
  </class>
```

And this is the create statement it creates:

```
create table DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE (
    DATABASE_TYPE_ID BIGINT not null,
   DispName NVARCHAR(255) null,
   primary key (DATABASE_TYPE_ID)
)
```

And this is the kind of insert statement I want to be able to run on it:

```
Insert into DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE (DATABASE_TYPE_ID,DISPNAME) values ('f5c7181e-e117-4a98-bc06-733638a3a264','DOC')
```

And this is the error I get when I try that:

```
Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 26306
> Insert into DBMON_DATABASE_TYPE (DATABASE_TYPE_ID,DISPNAME) values ('f5c7181e-e117-4a98-bc06-733638a3a264','DOC')
Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]
```

Once again my goal is to be able to use GUIDs as the ID column of my table, they don't even need to be auto generated, I can generate them manually in the Save/SaveOrUpdate methods of NHibernate.  If there is any other information you need to know please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mapping you need to identify that you want NHibernate to create a GUID in the database schema (it looks like you are generating your schema from the nhibernate mapping). Off the top of my head the following should work:

```
<id name="Id" column="DATABASE_TYPE_ID" type="Guid">
  <generator class="guid" />
</id>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
DATABASE_TYPE_ID BIGINT not null,
```

it needs to be

```
DATABASE_TYPE_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
```

I would strongly advice you to use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as a default instead since you are using it as a clustered index because it won't cause page splits and thus fragmentation, see here how to use it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx

Comment: Use Guid.Comb if generating IDs on the client side. Use NewSequentialID if the database is generating the IDs.

Comment: Comb units only work well when a single instance of the clientside is running. You can also assign GUid.NewGuid on the client side when you need run on multiple boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Dare I recommend using GuidComb's instead?